# function or syntax to copy/reference a cell value instead of a cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert in a cell the value calculated by a formula in another sheet.

If I use the something like `=MySheet!MyCell` Excel adds a reference to that cell and by doing that it actually re-use that formula.

As only option I know I can use "Paste Value" to copy the value from that source cell to my destination cell.

Is there any Excel function to just copy the value or do I have to implement a function/marco myself?

Comment: If you want a static copy of the value you will need to use `paste values` or some VBA to do something similar. Can you explain what your trying to do a little more?

Comment: Hi. I really like a function that does copy in my CELL A1 the value calculated from a formula in CELL B2. Ideally speaking when the CELL B2 gets updated also CELL A1 gets updated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel function or VBA function you can only make reference to the cells. To "Paste Value" you have to write VBA sub.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is *Paste Values*. you can do that either directly (you already mentioned it), or in VBA. Use

```
<your range>.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

within any code you want.

Note that you cannot write a `Function` to return the value pasted as value. This is tantamount to removing the formula which generated the value. The only way to **perform that action** do it is via a `Sub`, not as the result of a `Function` which **returns a value**.