# Automatically copy excel values not formulas

Tags: excel

I am looking for an automatic version of this feature:
https://www.technipages.com/excel-copy-and-paste-values-without-formulas

Is there a built in Excel function that can do this automatically without manually copy/pasting each cell? I have a column of functions and I want to have another column of values beside it.

Thanks!

Comment: See this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777973/function-or-syntax-to-copy-reference-a-cell-value-instead-of-a-cell-formula

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically", but this should at least speed up the process:

1. Select the cells you want to copy the content from and press CTRL+C
2. Click in the new cell and instead of using CTRL+V, use CTRL+ALT+V. This will open a dialogue box, in which you have to check "values". This can be done with another keyboard shortcut V (english version of Excel, might be something else in your language).

This might seem complex, but it's actually pretty fast.
Instead of pasting the cells with CTRL+V, you now paste the pure cell values with CTRL+ALT+V  +  V  (+ ENTER, depending on whether you use the english verion or not).

This at least saves you from using the mouse and clicking through additional menues. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks B.Thomann, I'm actually looking for something more closely resembling the link that @Brad Cunningham suggested. Only problem is i've never used VBA before and don't even know what i'm looking at!

Answer (score 0):

@J Connor, if I'm not mistaken you are in need of PROGRAMMING method, as you have written Automatically.

Here are few simple steps to get the Solution.

Method 1

Range("A1:B10").Copy Destination:=Range("E1")

Method 2

Range("A1:B10").Copy Range("E1").Select ActiveSheet.Paste

Few more I can suggest. ☺